# Static equilibrium of a small spring network

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spring, equilibrium, statics, network

Three springs $AB$, $OB$ and $CB$ with equal spring constants are fixed at the nodes $A$, $O$ and $C$ respectively and attached to a common node $B$, as shown below. The springs are at rest in this configuration.

[image: spring network pre-compression]

A genie exerts an unknown force that draws the node $A$ and $B$ closer to each other such that the length of the spring $AB$ is now 80% (or some other given/known fraction) of its rest length, as shown below:

[image: spring network post-compression]

How can I calculate the position of the node $B$ at which the spring system is in static equilibrium, for the given reduction of the length of the spring $AB$?

I've attempted to solve the problem by explicitly writing the forces acting on node $B$ (based on the techniques described in this [article](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Edzorin/numcomp08/springs_notes.pdf)) and trying to balance them, but this seems to introduce more variables to the problem and intuitively seems wrong.

Comment: Before you downvote please suggest what may be missing so that I can improve my question. Thank you.

Comment: This NOT homework or a textbook exercise. It is based on a problem that I formulated and diagrammed in LaTeX. I am not a trained Physicist so I will struggle to describe questions in a way that a trained Physicist would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A situation involving minimization or maximization of some function (here, minimization of the strain energy $\sum_i\frac{1}{2}k_ix_i^2$ stored in CB and OB, where $k_i$ is the spring constant and $x_i$ is the displacement) subject to some constraint (a constant distance from A to B, or $(x-x_0)^2+y^2=l^2$, where $(x,y)$ is the new location of point B, $x_0$ is the $x$-axis position of point A, and $l$ is the new length of spring AB) should always remind one of the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). Here, the Lagrangian is

$$\text{ℒ}=\sum_i\frac{1}{2}k_ix_i^2-\lambda\left[(x-x_0)^2+y^2-l^2\right],$$

One then solves $\nabla_{x,y,\lambda}\text{ℒ}=0$, or

$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial\text{ℒ}}{\partial x}&=0;\\
\frac{\partial\text{ℒ}}{\partial y}&=0;\\
\frac{\partial\text{ℒ}}{\partial \lambda}&=0,\end{align}$$ for $x$ and $y$ (and $\lambda$).

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to balance forces and that was leading nowhere fast. I expect this technique will scale to large networks.

Comment: Thank you again for this answer. I have gotten a LOT of mileage out of it.
Is $\lambda [(x_i - p)^2 + (y_i - q)^2]$ sufficient to express the constraint that a node $(x_i, y_i)$ is assigned a fixed position $(p, q)$?

Comment: Probably, although I could be missing something. Try it out!

Comment: I've gone full circle with this. Initially I created separate Lagrange parameters for each the $x_i$ and $y_i$, e.g. $\lambda_i(x_i - p)^2$ then I realize that differentiating by $\lambda_i$ yields $x_i = p$. Therefore I simply replaced all the $x_i$'s with $p$. The result is visually plausible.

Comment: Update: the above approach of having one Lagrange parameter per coordinate works.